# which imresize is fastest in Python

Tags: python, image, performance, interpolation

Currently, we need a interpolation in a Image. I have used the scipy.misc.imresize. This function has two drawback:

1. it can only output interger matrix, but I need a float result.
2. the speed of scipy.misc.imresize is a little slow

Comment: for 1. you can convert to float using [astype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)

Comment: I can convert the output to float. But I am afraid that the imresize convert my float image to interger resulting in loss some information. In addition, do you know which function of imresize is the faster?

Answer (score 0):

cv2.resize is slightly faster than scipy.misc.imresize